# How can I make an Ultrasonic Rangefinder (HC-SR04) accurate to +- 0.3cm arduino

Tags: c++, arduino

At the moment I am using the `NewPing.h` library ([Library Page](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/NewPing)) to get the distance. The code I have for doing this is as follows:

```
unsigned int uS = sonar.ping();
lcd.print(uS / US_ROUNDTRIP_CM);
lcd.print("cm");
```

This works however I would like the distance to be more precice. The range finder I purchased claimed to be "High Precision: Up to 0.3cm" so how do I achieve this?

Thankyou.

Comment: Could it be that both `uS` and `US_ROUNDTRIP_CM` are integers, so you are doing an integer division? Try making one of the values a `float`.

Comment: I second @JoachimPileborg's comment

Comment: So, what precision are you measuring?  Did sonar.ping_in() return different values?  sonar.ping_cm()?  Summary - just what is your complaint about 'precision'?

Comment: Well, don't fool the user, it only gets that accurate when you calibrate it and don't wait too long to make the next measurement. The speed of sound depends on temperature, humidity and altitude. Your copy/pasta is realistic, it doesn't promise more than you can deliver without writing a lot more code and manuals.  You are possibly missing the point of the fun of Arduino, instead of focusing on what it looks like, you ought to actually *use* it.  And, you know, observe the the neighbors moving half an inch closer when a thunderstorm passes through.  Real stuff.